# reorder elements in the dom by css position

Tags: javascript, css

How do I reorder dom elements based on the css position left?

I have 3 elements, with `left` values of 10, 20, and 30 percent, and `position: absolute`.

In the DOM, they're in the order `20, 10, 30` but I'd like to order them ascending according to the `left` attribute (`10, 20, 30`).

All three elements are inside a `div` with id `parent`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to loop through the child elements as an array so that they can be sorted, and then you need to reattach the children in the right order.  This can be done in pure JavaScript without jQuery:

```
var parent = document.getElemntById(parent),
    children = [];

// loop through the child nodes, add them to your array
// and remove them from the parent
for (var i = parent.childNodes.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    children.push(parent.childNodes[i]);
    parent.removeChild(parent.childNodes[i]);
}
// sort them based on the left property
children.sort(function(a,b){
    return window.getComputedStyle(a)['left'] - window.getComputedStyle(b)['left'];
});
// add them back to the parent in order
for (var i in children) {
    parent.appendChild(children[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, loop through the DOM elements you want to modify, put them in an array. Then sort the array by the property you want (in this case `window.getComputedStyle(elem)['left']`) and then re-insert the elements in the order the array tells you to.